# No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl'

Tags: makefile

Recently I switched to Linux on my PC. I was using the **W311MI Wireless N150 Pico USB Adapter** of Tenda. And while trying to make the `MakeFile` the following error occured -

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:217: archheaders] Error 2
```

Can someone please help me?

**Attachment:** Link to the MakeFile - https://www.tendacn.com/download/detail-2744.html

Comment: I have the same problem trying to build a driver on Ubuntu (POP OS 20.04) for DELL d300 docking station.